# Under parent all the child elements are not getting in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in mysql table columns and data like below

```
 id   refid    name   userdefined
 1    0         A      
 2    0         B
 3    0         c
 4    1         A1
 5    1         A2
 6    1         A3
 7    4         a1     CCC
 8    4         a2     MNO
 9    2         B1
 10   2         B2     BQW
 11   3         C1
 12   3         C2
 13   11        CEF    AAA
 14   11        DEF    ABC
```

I want to display the parent elements like A and B and C like tab items,
if I click on the A tab item I want to display all the child elements and grandchild elements.In my case, I am getting only the first child elements only. I have tried different ways but I am not getting the result as expected, and I searched on google, it's saying like recursive function.if there is any way to do without using recursive function please help me thanks in advance.

```
   <?php
       require ('Assests/connection/connection.php');
          //iam retriving parent elements only
          $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from test where refid=".'0');
          $tab_list='';
          $tab_content='';
           $i=0;
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
          if($i==0) {
           //for the first parent element i am adding class as active
           $tab_list .= '
           <li class="active"><a href="#'.$row["id"].'" data-
            toggle="tab">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
            $tab_content .= '
             <div id="'.$row["id"].'" class="tab-pane fade in active">';
          }
          else
              { 
                //for remaining parents adding li class
                $tab_list .= '
                  <li><a href="#'.$row["id"].'" data-
              toggle="tab">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
             $tab_content .= '
             <div id="'.$row["id"].'" class="tab-pane fade">';
            }
              //i am passing the retrivedid
              $test_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE refid = 
               '".$row["id"]."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $test_query);

          while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
           //Adding the checkboxes for child elemens
           $tab_content .=
              "<li class='lichild'><input type='checkbox' 
               name='names[]'value='". 
               $rows['id'] ."'>".$rows['name'];
        }

          $tab_content .= '<div style="clear:both"></div></div>';
          $i++;

    }
   ?>
```

Comment: why my question downvoted any reason.